# Inheritance in C# predefined interfaces not clear

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I'll explain the question with an **example**.

The C# predefined interface `IList<T>` inherits `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` & `IEnumerable`.

The C# predeined interface `ICollection<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` & `IEnumerable`.

Given the above statements, my question is, why are the interfaces `IEnumerable<T>` & `IEnumerable` being explicitly inherited in `IList<T>` becuase they are already being inherited in `ICollection<T>`.

In essence, wouldn't the below suffice?

`public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T> { //code }
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable { //code }`

I want to know why have the interfaces been inherited explicitly while they were inherited as a part of other interface.

Comment: because it's clearer and you don't have to know or check if `ICollection` inherits `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Also, see source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ilist.cs,b19f71a84062554b